# Spring application.properties database connection

Tags: spring-boot, application.properties

I didn't mention the mysql  port number in application.properties but its works fine. How it happen?

i.e in application.properties

spring.datasource.url=jdbc:mysql://localhost/database_name

I want to know that it works fine due to the default port is 3306 for MySql? If YES then If I changed the port number to the 3033 then also it works if I didn't mention port in the url ?

Comment: It will only work by default for port 3306 because that is, as stated, the default port. If you run MySQL on another port it will fail.

Comment: can you add the pom.xml file and the configuration files please

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned in the comments, this works because then the default port (3306) is assumed. This can also be found in [the documentation](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/connector-j/8.1/en/connector-j-reference-jdbc-url-format.html):

> Single-host connections without adding host-specific properties:
>
> - The `hosts` part is written in the format of host:port. This is an example of a simple single-host connection URL:
>
>   ```
>   jdbc:mysql://host1:33060/sakila
>   ```
> - `host` can be an IPv4 or an IPv6 host name string, and in the latter case it must be put inside square brackets, for example “[1000:2000::abcd].” When host is not specified, the default value of localhost is used.
> - `port` is a standard port number, i.e., an integer between 1 and 65535. **The default port number for an ordinary MySQL connection is 3306**, and it is 33060 for a connection using the X Protocol. **If `port` is not specified, the corresponding default is used.**

*(Emphasis is my own)*

---

So if you run your database on port 3303, then it won't work because the JDBC driver will still use the default port, which is 3306. In this case you have to configure your JDBC URL as:

```
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:mysql://localhost:3303/database_name
```